# Check android purchase status but return the purchase token was not found

Tags: android, google-api, in-app-purchase, google-play-services, in-app-billing

I refered [google play android api](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/products/get) to check the purchase and consumption status of an in-app item. 
For some orders, I can get right result,but some return the error as below:

```
error: {
errors: [
{
domain: "global",
reason: "purchaseTokenNotFound",
message: "The purchase token was not found.",
locationType: "parameter",
location: "token"
}
],
code: 404,
message: "The purchase token was not found."
}
```

Purchase token is provided by google, does it can be faked?

I found if I cancel the google order, then check the purchase status,it will return the purchase token was not found. if not, i will get the right purchase status.

Hope somebody can help.

Comment: Do you check json signature? If you use an unique server-generated developer payload (e.g. aes encrypted timestamp + product id + user id) and Google json signature (checked with your developer RSA public key) is correct - maybe there is no need to verify purchaseToken?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are selling the same INAPP product to the same user muliple times within a short period, then it's very likely that all access tokens except the last purchase will return a **404** code.

For example:

**john@example.com** went to your app and purchased **com.example.test.product** a few times, you will probaly notice within your records (or Google Wallet Merchant account) that it's the same user buying the product.

When you go to check the last purchase from this user, then the following is likely to appear

```
{
kind: "androidpublisher#inappPurchase",
purchaseTime: "1409823171827",
purchaseState: "0",
consumptionState: "1",
developerPayload: "My Product | Ref | 1409823162466"
}
```

and yet if you were to check his previous tokens, then it's very likely that his purchases will return **404**!

I had read somewhere (can't remember where) that the purchase token created for each purchase is basically based on the inapp product and google user.  Therefore, it's very likely that each purchase will "destroy" any previous purchase token created for the same user.

Hope this explanation helps.  I am constantly having this problem everyday when my server is attempting to connect to the Google API and check the transactions.  Perhaps one day somebody will read this and provide a solution :)

Comment: Are you talking about managed (non-consumables) or unmanaged(consumables) products?

Comment: sorry! just seen your response... talking about unmanaged(consumables)

Answer (score 1):

The documents are misleading. You don't need to use this API to verify purchases.

Mobile app have **INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA** and **INAPP_DATA_SIGNATURE** from **getBuyIntent** method.

You can verify the purchase with the signature and your **public key**.

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html#getBuyIntent

You can find the **public key** on  `Google Play Developer Console` -> `YOUR_APP` -> `service and API`

```
package main

import (
        "crypto"
        "crypto/rsa"
        "crypto/sha1"
        "crypto/x509"
        "encoding/base64"
        "encoding/pem"
        "fmt"
)

//replace const below with your own.
const (
        pubKeyPEM=`-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
Some thing like this
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----`
        data = `purchase data from getBuyIntent API`
        sign = `purchase data signature from getBuyIntent API`

)

func Panic(err error) {
        if err != nil {
                panic(err)
        }
}

func main() {

        PEMBlock, _ := pem.Decode([]byte(pubKeyPEM))
        if PEMBlock == nil {
                Panic(fmt.Errorf("Could not parse Public Key PEM"))
        }
        if PEMBlock.Type != "PUBLIC KEY" {
                Panic(fmt.Errorf("Found wrong key type"))
        }
        pubkey, err := x509.ParsePKIXPublicKey(PEMBlock.Bytes)
        if err != nil {
                Panic(err)
        }

        // compute the sha1
        h := sha1.New()
        h.Write([]byte(data))

        // decode b64 signature
        signature, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(sign)
        Panic(err)

        // Verify
        err = rsa.VerifyPKCS1v15(pubkey.(*rsa.PublicKey), crypto.SHA1, h.Sum(nil), signature)
        Panic(err)

        // It verified!
        fmt.Println("OK")
}
```