# Android In-app billing subscription verification failing

Tags: android, google-api-dotnet-client, android-billing

I have an Android app which makes use of Android In-App Billing V3 to make subscription purchases.
Once the subscription is purchased in the app, information is sent to server which verifies the signature and purchase token and gets additional information about subscription. I am using Google API .Net library to do this.

```
PurchasesResource.SubscriptionsResource.GetRequest subscriptionGetRequest =
                    service.Purchases.Subscriptions.Get(packageName, productId, purchaseToken);
SubscriptionPurchase subscriptionPurchase = subscriptionGetRequest.Execute();
```

This has been working fine for almost a year, but since last few days lot of these API calls are failing with following error:

```
[Google.GoogleApiException]
Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
The purchase token was not found. [404]
Errors [
    Message[The purchase token was not found.] Location[token - parameter] Reason[purchaseTokenNotFound] Domain[global]
]
```

At the same time, few other purchases are being verified correctly, so i don't think there is anything wrong in the code or the way i am calling Google API, but i would like to know if anyone else has faced this issue earlier.

Edit:
This is not same as question [Check android purchase status but return the purchase token was not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25401759/check-andriod-purchase-status-but-return-the-purchase-token-was-not-found), which seems to be about consumable products. I am selling subscription products here and users do not purchase same products again and again in quick succession.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check andriod purchase status but return the purchase token was not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25401759/check-andriod-purchase-status-but-return-the-purchase-token-was-not-found)

Comment: @DalmTo that question and answer talks about consumable products

Comment: @7F14T any luck with this? facing the same issue with subscription products

Comment: @kb_14 the error hasn't re-occurred in last few days, which leads me to believe this was caused by something on Google servers.